# Wi-Fi won't turn on after upgrading to Catalina

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi, catalina

I upgraded my early 2015 Macbook Pro to Catalina and I can't turn on Wi-Fi. I opened Network settings and there was a "do not lock" button for a few seconds and then it changed to "Turn Wi-Fi on". I clicked on it and nothing happened.

I tried restarting Mac and SMC and NVRAM/PRAM resets but it didn't help. I also can't run Wireless diagnostics -- I click on the app and a window pops up for a second and then disappears. In the Network app, the Wi-fi interface isn't listed in the interface options for a new surface ("+" button).

What do I do to resolve Wi-Fi connectivity?  I don't have other connections to the internet (only through Wi-fi).